# UK Visa - stated I'd be traveling with family, now I'm not

Tags: uk-visa

I'm from the US. I created, submitted online, and paid for my UK Tier 2 visa application. I have not yet had my biometric appointment nor sent the application in to the UK office.

In my online application I stated I'd be traveling with my family as that was the plan. Just recently, our plans have changed and my family will be following a couple months behind me.

Since I can no longer edit the application, do I need to cancel it, request a refund, and recreate my application?